# How to access localy installed Screwturn Wiki from networked machines

Tags: ip, localhost, wiki, screwturn

I installed Screwturn Wiki using WebMatrix 2 and this tutorial: [Installing ScrewTurn Wiki using WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/installing-screwturn-wiki-using-webmatrix), Now I have Screwturn Wiki running on my machine at `http://localhost:4422/Default.aspx` but have no idea how to allow other users on our network to access the wiki. I read that they may need to use my ip address instead of localhost (I Understand localhost is specific to the machine itself) but a direct replacement in the url doesn't seem to work.

```
http://(ip address):4422/Default.aspx
```

How can I get other machines to access screwturn as it is installed to my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they need to access it via IP address, use `ipconfig` to determinate your IP address and other users will be able to use that in order to access your application

Comment: Perhapps I don't understand how they need to use it specifically then. I mentioned that I had them try using my ip address as it is returned from ipconfig in the url but it didn't work. Is it just my ip address/Default.aspx?

Comment: no, it's http : //_IP_ADDRESS_:4422/Default.aspx (no spaces)